# Zuul not forwading if have custom security configuration in microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

I am facing issue when use zuul. Firstly I give information with my project. I use Zuul and Consul together in my project and I am trying to create own authentication and authorization system. For this I decide to use oAuth2 protocol with Spring Boot.

So in this architecture,

Zuul is receive request and control access token. If access token doesn't exist in header, route oAuth service. oAuth service authentication user and return access token to client. Client send header with access token and Zuul check access token than route suitable service.

Finally i use jwt as access token and store as jwt data store.

Let's pass issue.

Firstly that's problem, Zuul forwarding request to services that doesn't make to security configuration or make default configuration. But not forwading to services that make custom to security configuration.

Now Zuul services is resource service and have separate an authentication service in my project.

Now if i use only `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation in boot class at Authentication Service. Zuul forward request but i don't want it to be this way.

Additional Info : According to my research If `@EnableAutoConfiguration and @Component`annotation use together, Spring boot scan custom configuration but only use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` then Spring boot not scan custom configuration. Instead of this, Spring boot use default configuration.

If I use  `@EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan` together in Authentication Service than Zuul throw error as below.

What is the problem? I try every solution but didn't work and came here as last resort Please help me.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:190) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]

Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: auth-service
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10352) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10319) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.M5.jar:2.0.0.M5]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.4.jar:1.3.4]
```

Spring Cloud Version :

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.M5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

If you want firsty i put Zuul Service yml properties.

```
server:

  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-service
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckPath: /health
        healthChechInterval: 15s
        prefer-ip-address: true
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        watch:
          enabled: true
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      percentage: 1
zuul:
  routes:
    accounts-service:
      path: /account/**
      serviceId: accounts-service
    product-service:
      path: /product/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      serviceId: product-service
    auth-service:
      path: /auth/**
      serviceId: auth-service

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    sso:
      loginPath: http://localhost:8081/login
    client:
      clientId: zuulfilter
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8081/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      preferTokenInfo:false
```

And Zuul Boot Class

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ZuulServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulServiceApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

And Zuul Web Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(-10)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    private static final String CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";


    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                     .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/auth/login", "/account/**","/product/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                     .and()
                     .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(requestMatcher()).csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                     .and()
                     .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                     .addFilterAfter(oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                     .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }


    private OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter =
                new OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.setStateless(false);

        return oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationManager oAuth2AuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setResourceId("zuulservice");
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(resourceServerTokenServices);
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setClientDetailsService(null);

        return oAuth2AuthenticationManager;
    }

    private RequestMatcher requestMatcher() {
        return new RequestMatcher() {

            private final Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$");

            private final AntPathRequestMatcher [] antPathRequestMatcher = { new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**")};
            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {

                if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches()) {
                    return false;
                }

                for(AntPathRequestMatcher matcher : antPathRequestMatcher) {
                    if(matcher.matches(request)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    private static Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

                if(csrfToken != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, csrfToken.getToken());
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    cookie.setSecure(true);
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

            }
        };
    }

    private static CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        csrfTokenRepository.setHeaderName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME);
        return csrfTokenRepository;
    }

}
```

Now secondly Authentication yml properties.

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  application:
    name: auth-service
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        healthCheckPath: /health
        healthChechInterval: 15s
        prefer-ip-address: true
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        watch:
          enabled: true
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      percentage: 1


security:
  basic:
    enabled : false
```

Authentication Server Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("zuulfilter")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8081")
            .scopes("openid");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("examplekeystore.jks"), "1234".toCharArray());
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("examplekeystore"));
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }

}
```

Authentication Web Security Configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class LoginConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {


            httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll();
        httpSecurity.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().
        and().
        authorizeRequests().
        anyRequest().
        authenticated();


    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {

        PasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
        String password = encoder.encode("1234");
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(encoder).
                    withUser("deneme").
                    password(password).
                    roles("USER");
    }

}
```

Thanks for help already.

Comment: Can you see `auth-service` registered on Consul?

Comment: Yes I can see, already If I use only EnableAutoConfiguration in auth-service boot class, Zuul find auth-service but If I use EnableAutoConfiguraton and ComponentScan together than return above error.

Comment: Does upgrading to boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and Finchley.M8 yield the same results?

Comment: I can't tell from your answer, but that fixed it?

Comment: Yes i changed versions through that you asked question and fix it. If you want, write answer to down for those who faced this problem.Thus we can make it visible answer.